# Map multi domain only use htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'm Vietnamese so my english is not good.
I have problem for my cms.
I want to map sub domain to as link via htaccess
Example:
I have links as

```
?user=example&op=value => example.domain.com/value/ and
domain.com/?user=example1&op=value1 => example1.domain.com/value1/ or
domain.com/?user=example2&op=value2 => example2.domain.com/value2/
..... ....
```

and many.

I'm using shares hosting so i can't edit file http.config or any one I'm sorry because my English.
Thank all

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your `domain.com` site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if its domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC] 
#capture the user and op query string values
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)user=([^&]+)&op=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC] 
#and redirect to subdomain with appropriate value
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.%{HTTP_HOST}/%3/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @user1186130 What URL did you test with and what was the result?

Comment: You should redirect the www to the non-www just to be safe with the above code.